# проект на Yii2, проблема наверное с типами в базе данных

Tags: mysql, yii2

Пробовал заливать на хостинг где тип таблиц InnoDB всё работает, но на хостинге где тип таблиц MyISAM и естественно не работает. Пробовал поменять тип на хостинге не помогло. Подскажите как решить данную проблему. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: на всякий случай]

Comment: уберите скрин и покажите код.

Comment: Код целой \views\layouts\main.php (не влазит много символов) да и за чем, я получаю массив и foreach-м по ключам вывожу список, обращаю внимание на то что на локалке всё работает,на хостингах (разных платный и бесплатный) где изначально таблицы хранятся в InnoDB тоже работает а там где тип MyISAM (2 хостинга тестил) не работает. Вьюху скинуть могу даже целиком но не думаю что это поможет тем более на скриншоте именно этот стрёмный кусок и видно.

Comment: может быть надо писать `<?php foreach` и `<?php endforach` , т.к. на хостах может быть отключено `short_tags` ?

Comment: спасибо, это именно то что нужно, действительно short_tags.